# BitTorrent sends packets as UDP instead of TCP

Tags: tcp, udp, wireshark, bittorrent, packet-sniffers

I am analyzing BitTorrent with WireShark, and according to the specification and Wiki, BitTorrent should do the exchange using TCP, but I am getting the entire exchange in UDP.

I read up on DHT that is supposed to use UDP, but as I understand it, it only uses UDP to store your IP info in the hash table. The exchange should still be in TCP right? How come I am getting the entire download in UDP-packet exchange instead of TCP?

Answer (score 0):

The BitTorrent protocol has been extended to use UDP with the [uTP - uTorrent transport protocol (BEP29)](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html) extension.